# Maximal element in set with binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

We have a  binary relation on $Z^2$: $(x_1, y_1)R(x_2, y_2) \iff x_1 \leq x_2, y_1 \leq y_2$. Find maximal elements in the following set: $F = \{(x, y)|x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$.

We can't say that it is $(2,2)$ because it's not in $F$. Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maxi*mal* elements, not Maxi*mum* elements.  Make sure you know the difference.  Have you any intuition as far as what the set $F$ looks like?  Maybe a common shape from geometry?  Have you considered what the border of that looks like and whether any values on the border fit the description of being maximal in your relation?  All of the border... or only a portion of the border?  What about elements not on the border... could they have been maximal?

Comment: If $x_1^2+y_1^2 = 4$ with $x_1,y_1$ both non-negative... given some positive values $\epsilon,\varepsilon>0$ then what can you say about $(x_1+\epsilon)^2 + (y_1+\varepsilon)^2$?

Comment: It's a circle with the shifted center

Comment: They're $(0,2),\ (1,1)$ and $(2,0)$.

Comment: @Andy Circle *with a shifted center*?  What makes you think the center was shifted?  If it were over all real numbers, it is a circle of radius $2$ with center at the origin.  Since we look only at integers, it is just those grid points which lie inside of said circle.  Still, the intuition about the real number case helps just as much here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Seems (2,2) is maximal element, but not maximum?

Comment: (2,2) is not in F.  It does not deserve such a label.  (2,0) is maximal.  So is (0,2).  Neither is "bigger" than the other

Comment: I don't get @Berci's answer, we can't say that (0,2) < (1,1)

Comment: @JMoravitz and (1,1) is not I guess. And is it ok that we can't say (2,0) is less than (0,2) and vice-versa?

Comment: (1,1) is also maximal *in the relation over the integers*. All times it is related to something different it is on the right in xRy.  Do you see why that is no longer the case if dealing with reals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130492/discussion-between-andy-and-jmoravitz).